# How can I collect all formdata which repeating components on the same page into a single formdata in Angular?

Tags: angular, file-upload, append, form-data

I have a component that upload multiple files and this component is repeated on the same page. I want to get all formdata into to the single formdata. How can I do this?

**Component HTML**

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileSelect($event, docType)"/>
<input type="file" (change)="fileSelect($event, docType)"/>
<input type="file" (change)="fileSelect($event, docType)"/>
```

**Component TS**

```
formData = new FormData();


fileSelect(evt, type) {
    this.formData.append('doc', <File>event.target.files[0], type);
}
```

**Component Include in parent.html**

```
<div class="block-1">
    <app-file-upload></app-file-upload>
</div>

<div class="block-2">
    <app-file-upload></app-file-upload>
</div>

<div class="block-3">
    <app-file-upload></app-file-upload>
</div>
<button (click)="sendAll()">Send All Files</button>
```

When upload files separately, created formData only applied to the relevant component (own scope). How can I collect all formData into the single formData when click the send button.

Comment: sould be solved using reactive forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In parent component we can query list of child components through `@ViewChildren()` decoration.

```
@ViewChildren(AppFileUploadComponent) 
fileUploadComponents: QueryList<AppFileUploadComponent>;
```

After in the `sendAll()` method we can iterate over the child components and can get the `formData` property from the `AppFileUploadComponent` instance and then can store to final `FormData`.

```
sendAll() {
  let finalFormData = new FormData();
  this.fileUploadComponents.forEach((component) => {
    let formData = component.formData;
    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      finalFormData.append(key, value);
    })
  });
  // final form Data
  console.log(finalFormData)
}
```

The complete code is available in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdflro?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `@Output` decorator in `<app-file-upload>` component.
In first option, you could do:

```
@Component(...)
export class AppFileUploadComponent{

    @Output('onFileSelect')
    onFileSelect: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    ...

    fileSelect(evt, type) {
        this.onFileSelect.emit(/* Emit the data you want*/);
        // do other magical stuff here

    }
}
```

And in the parent component template:

```
<div class="block-3">
    <app-file-upload (onFileSelect)="appendFile($event)"></app-file-upload>
</div>
```

Parent .ts file

```
...

appendFile = (data) => {
    /*
      You can append the data to an array
      to use it in sendAll() method
    */    
}
```